# Check for network connectivity every second, for 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

I am currently checking for a valid Internet connection when my application starts (the app is launched on boot) but more often then not, the wifi hasn't kicked in when the check is made, so it comes back false.

I'd like to have the check run for 5-10 seconds (without lokcing up the app) and if after 10 seconds the status is still false, stop checking.

Here is my current (poor) implementation of simply checking constanlty until the status is true:

```
while(!isConnected()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I'm fairly sure I need to use a Timer or even a Runnable Thread? But I can't seem to find anyone doing anything like what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

1. Listen for [CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges) intent;
2. Start IntentService and check status yourself and if it changes send notification to your activity.

Comment: How would I put a timeout on this? E.g check for the intent for 10 seconds, then give up listening.

Comment: You don't need to check for intent, you simply received it if something changed. To run repetitive task you can use Handler with postDelayed or Timer.

Comment: I understand that I receive the change for the Intent, but how do I stop listening for the change? e.g. Listen for Connection state for 20 seconds, then stop listening (to allow me to manually start something)

Comment: start service and register and unregister recevier dynamically.